# obtener url de la miniatura de categorías woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

tengo la siguiente duda. Estoy haciendo una tienda online con woocommerce y en ella tengo productos, y estos tienen categorías. Pues bien,a la hora de crear la categoría en el back office de wordpress, se añade una imagen/miniatura a esta. Necesito obtener la url de esa imagen. Cualquier función probado hasta ahora como wp_get_attachment_url() o wp_get_attachment_image_src() me devuelven las imagenes de los productos. Yo quiero la miniatura de la categoría (adjunto captura):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo único que he conseguido hasta ahora es obtener el parámetro de la URL tag_id, pero este no me sirve de nada a la hora de intentar localizar la imagen...
¿Alguien tiene alguna idea?
Gracias por adelantado.

Comment: Hola... Haz intentado dar click derecho sobre la imagen miniatura y de las opciones que te aparezcan abrir la imagen en una pestaña nueva?... La otra sería click derecho sobre tu página y dar click en la opción ver código fuente..? Estas opciones creo que te servirán.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba agregando lo siguiente en tu functions.php

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description', 'woocommerce_category_image', 2 );
function woocommerce_category_image() {
    if ( is_product_category() ){
        global $wp_query;
        $cat = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
        $thumbnail_id = get_term_meta( $cat->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true );
        $image = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumbnail_id );
        if ( $image ) {
            echo '<img src="' . $image . '" alt="' . $cat->name . '" />';
        }
    }
}
```

Parece que debes tener el gancho `woocommerce_archive_description` en la plantilla del tema, pero puedes usar cualquier otro gancho, como `wp_body_open();` o alguno personalizado.

Fuentes: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-display-category-image-on-category-archive/

Comment: Muchísimas gracias de nuevo amigo! Lo había conseguido hacer sacando la ruta a mano pero no era exactamente lo que buscaba... Me has dado justo lo que llevo dos días buscando. Muchísimas gracias!!